# Break a CGRect into 4 variables

Tags: objective-c

Given that drawRect takes a CGRect 'rect', how can I create 4 separate CGFloat variables with the individual values of rect (x,y,width,height)?  I need to use the variables on an individual basis to determine certain drawing scales within the drawRect method.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
 CGFLoat x = ***x value of rect***;
 CGFLoat y = ***y value of rect***;
 CGFloat width = ***width value of rect***;
 CGFloat height = ***height value of rect***;
 }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you brush up on some basic C materials as the question is pretty basic C structure stuff (no big deal -- we were all there once).

Given:

```
struct CGPoint {
  CGFloat x;
  CGFloat y;
};
typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint;

/* Sizes. */

struct CGSize {
  CGFloat width;
  CGFloat height;
};
typedef struct CGSize CGSize;

/* Rectangles. */

struct CGRect {
  CGPoint origin;
  CGSize size;
};
typedef struct CGRect CGRect;
```

You want:
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
         CGFLoat x = rect.origin.x;
         CGFLoat y = rect.origin.y;
         CGFloat width = rect.size.width;
         CGFloat height = rect.size.height;
     }

Or, better yet, because there are functions for such madness:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     CGFLoat x = CGRectGetMinX(rect);
     CGFLoat y = CGRectGetMinY(rect);
     CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(rect);
     CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(rect);
 }
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  

I know my skills are rusty, so much to learn

Comment: Yup -- no worries -- like I said, we've all been there.  Xcode generally does a wonderful job of taking you to the definition of something if you cmd-dbl-click on the type.

Answer (score 3):

```
 CGFLoat x = rect.origin.x;
 CGFLoat y = rect.origin.y;
 CGFloat width = rect.size.width;
 CGFloat height = rect.size.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of a CGRect is defined as such

```
struct CGRect {
   CGPoint origin;
   CGSize size;
};
typedef struct CGRect CGRect;
```

Which means you can do this:

```
rect.origin.x
rect.origin.y
rect.size.width
rect.size.height
```

Comment: Bit of an incomplete declaration, thar.  Assumes you know what a CGPoint and CGSize are.

Comment: agreed, your answer is much more complete :)